# Unity: Game object delete itself from hierarchy when I play animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator, collider

When I play animation which change offset polygon collider 2D the gameobject with animator destroy itself in hierarchy for no reason. When I remove collider offset the animation start working properly once again but without collider it's unusable for the game. Until this day it was working properly but suddenly it has broken for no apparent reason. I haven't change animation in any way. Only thing I did was importing Google Play Service and installing some SDk's. I was trying to find solution the whole day but came up with nothing and now I am desperate.

Comment: This is weird. You should try to reproduce this bug on an empty project to make sure nothing in your code destroys your GameObject.

Comment: When I remove collider offset movement from animation it start working again but when I turn it back again it's still broken and my code only run animation so it has nothing to do with game object. And it looks like there is no one who has the same problem.

Comment: I understand that, but if you can't reproduce the bug in an empty project with your animation, it means that you need something else to reproduce the bug. The worst that could happen to you is that it's a Unity3d bug. In this case, you'll need a minimal example to report the bug to Unity3d's team.

Comment: If you can find steps to reproduce - send bug report to Unity